# Unable to send an email to multiple Email Ids

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I am working on an Email Trigger Action in SharePoint Designer 2013 for SharePoint On-Prem.

I have used multiple Email Ids (Group Id & some individual person's Id) to which I want to send an Email.

The problem is that Email triggers to only Individual Person's Id and not to Group Email Id.
I am wondering, why it is happening? Are there some configuration issues with those email Ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an email to the group of people using SharePoint Group. You need to make sure all users have right email address updated. To confirm you can use write to history list option to see all users email address fetched by workflow so that you can isolate issue further.